# c# LINQ to filter XML, keep tree hierarchy

Tags: xml

I have filtered my data like this IEnumerable

```
   xDOCfiltered = xDOC
        .Where(k => 
            (
                ( k.Attribute("Object_Heading").Value.Trim() == "Author" && k.Parent.Attribute("Milestones").Value.Contains(milestone) )
                //
                || k.Attribute("Milestones").Value.Contains(milestone)
            ) 

            && filterUID.IsMatch(k.Attribute("Unique_ID").Value.Trim())
            && GetHierarchy(k).First() == "Code"
            )
        ;
```

Now I just discovered that when I use

```
foreach (XElement xobj in xGDMfiltered)
{
...
...
XNode previousNode = xobj.PreviousNode;
...
...

}
```

My PREV node is referring to original xDOC structure, not filtered one :(
I am not clear, the xDOCfiltered returned by LINQ is just a plain list, all hierarchy information is lost?

It appears to be and somehow is logical, linq will return a collection.

I load my structure as follows

```
            x= XDocument.Load(myXml);

            xDOC = x.Element("root").Descendants("record");
```

Can I filter somehow and still keep (reconstruct) the hierarchy?
Somthing like delete all nodes filtered by LINQ expression?

Thank you very much in advance,

PS.
First thing that comes into my mind is to do a foreach to filtered list and remove that nodes from x document but there is a more elegant solution?

This takes several minutes, original unfiltered doc has >18.000 nodes!

Comment: Your question is unclear - it's not obvious what you're trying to achieve to start with. If you clarify your question, ideally including a [mcve], you may well find there's a simpler approach than the one you've posted as an answer.

Comment: @Jon, I tried my best. I cannot post 18k records of XML here. The idea is that group of XElements doesn't keep original nested hierarchy as it were in XML document. This is after filtering with LINQ. So accessing node.Previous property will be non sense.

Comment: I didn't ask for 18K records. I asked for a [mcve]. All you've got to show is something representative that we can use to understand what your question is. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone will need this, I fixed by negating all clauses in first place, then remove all not-matching nodes at once. This is very fast comparing to foreach remove.

```
            x.Element("root").Descendants("record") // delete if
                .Where(k => 
                    !( // NEGATE so keep this kind of objects

                        // contains desired milestone
                        k.Attribute("Milestones").Value.Contains(milestone)

                        || // or

                        (k.Attribute("Object_Heading").Value.Trim() == "Author" && k.Parent.Attribute("Milestones").Value.Contains(milestone))
                    ) 

                    // or if UID is not in this format
                    || !filterUID.IsMatch(k.Attribute("Unique_ID").Value.Trim()) // and this format for UID

                    // or if first parent (except root) is not a Code  
                    || GetHierarchy(k).First() != "Code"

                    ).Remove()
                ;

                xDOCfiltered =
                    x.Element("root").Descendants("record");
```